# How to render image in a filtered Spark DataFrame

Tags: image, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have loaded a datatable to a DataFrame containing images (`content` column) in DataBricks with Spark:

```
df_test = (spark.read.format("delta").table(data_table)).select(col("content"), col("label_index"))
```

it correctly displays images with `display(df_test)`.

But after some filtering of rows on the dataframe, display does not work anymore:

```
a = [3,6,9]
df_test_filtered = [df_test.collect()[i] for i in a]
display(df_test_filtered)
```

I am aware that `df_test_filtered` is a list of Rows now, so I also tried to convert it back to a proper DataFrame like this:

```
df_test_cols = df_test.columns
df_test2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=df_test_filtered, schema = df_test_cols)
display(df_test2)
```

In both cases the result is sth like:

[image]

That would be the raw binary content I would get if I turned off *Show image preview* checkbox of the original (unfiltered) DataFrame:

[image]

But for the filtered one, I don't have this checkbox. Apparently according to the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/visualizations/#display-image-type

the method `display` should automatically recognize images but it doesn't. Any idea how to force it to display them correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I assume it doesn't work anymore because you leave the pyspark context. Instead of collecting you could stay in pyspark for the filtering.

If you want to filter the rows e.g. 3,6,9 you could assign a row number using the pyspark function `monotonically_increasing_id()`

```
df = df.withColumn('id', monotonically_increasing_id())
df = df.withColumn('row_number', row_number().over(Window.orderBy('id')))
```

Then you can use `filter()` to filter to the rows with the row numbers you need.

```
df = df.filter("row_number IN (3,6,9)")
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like having 'id' already does the trick. Did you create 'row_number' just to increase 'id' by 1?